# How to stop closing and opening of browser in each cucumber scenario execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have written few scenarios in one cucumber feature file and its execute with Selenium web driver.

Cucumber feature

Scenario 1
Scenario 2
Scenario 3

When ever I execute the tests it openup new browser session and close it at the end. I would like to run the 3 tests in same browser session.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please include the code of how you are doing the initialization of the driver. Thanks.

Comment: What language are you writing in?

AfterFeature seems to be the hook you are looking for, which will allow for closing the browser after all the scenarios within a feature file, but for actual implementation details, it depends on which language and version of cucumber in that language that you are using.

Comment: Also please include the command you are using to run your tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JUnit Annotations below in your Test Runner not Test Hook.

```
      @BeforeClass
      public static void setUp(){

      openABrowser();
     }

      @AfterClass
      public static void tearDown(){

      closeABrowser();

}
```